# Are experience awards additive in Battlestations?

Tags: battlestations

I'm having trouble deciphering the v1.1 rules in general, but especially whether some experience awards are additive.

For example, are the rewards for attempting the mission and the experience for completing the mission additive? That is, if Jimbo goes on a mission and succeeds, does he get the 50 exp for trying and 100 exp for winning or just the 100 exp for winning?

Also, if a character goes on a mission (50 exp) and dies (100 prestige) but the crew wins the mission (100 exp), what is he awarded? 150 exp and 100 prestige? Or just 50 experience and 100 prestige?

Finally, are the bonus awards for driving off / capturing / destroying enemy warships / freighters given out for the ships listed in the mission, or only when they show up for some other reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, for RPGs where the rules are the game, it is difficult to get a copy of the rules to answer questions like these. This means that we have to rely on designers answering these questions definitively on various forums.

**Are the rewards for attempting the mission and the experience for completing the mission additive?**

They are additive, The designer [Jeff Siadek](http://boardgamegeek.com/user/ourhero) answers that [question here](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/582439#582439)

> **3. Is the reward of 100 XP for a completed mission in addition to or instead of the 50 XP for an attempted mission?**
>
> A character that completes a mission gets 150 experience. 50 for trying and 100 more for succeeding.

I have not found official answers for the remaining two questions.

**If a character goes on a mission (50 exp) and dies (100 prestige) but the crew wins the mission (100 exp), what is he awarded?** Players on BGG have said the [following](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/5024890#5024890) .

> Killed crewmembers do not get experience but they do gain prestige for going out in a heroic manner.

**Finally, are the bonus awards for driving off / capturing / destroying enemy warships / freighters given out for the ships listed in the mission, or only when they show up for some other reason?** [response](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/7782748#7782748)

> you don't get any extra xp for caputring/destroying the mission objective, nor extra credits. That's only for ships beyond the scope of the mission.
>
> If say another ship arrived to assist the target and you destroyed that, then you get the size x 10 exp.